# Invisible text in menu, search, and upper navigation bar

Tags: gui

I suddenly have all my text invisible in the menu, search and upper navigation bar including the time.

See the following image for illustration:

[image: No text anywhere in menu]

Answer (score 1):

Changing the value for text size for "big text" in "parameters", "universal access" then reverting it to normal fixed the problem.